# How to remove test ad text on google admob

Tags: flutter, admob

I just implement google admob on my flutter application and it shows on my mobile application but I kept seeing this "Test Ad" text on top of the banner and interestial ad. Please how can I remove this?

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Firebase AdMob Test Ads Demo App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  InterstitialAd myInterstitial;

  InterstitialAd buildInterstitialAd() {
    return InterstitialAd(
      adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        if (event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
          myInterstitial..load();
        } else if (event == MobileAdEvent.closed) {
          myInterstitial = buildInterstitialAd()..load();
        }
        print(event);
      },
    );
  }

  void showInterstitialAd() {
    myInterstitial..show();
  }

  void showRandomInterstitialAd() {
    Random r = new Random();
    bool value = r.nextBool();

    if (value == true) {
      myInterstitial..show();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myInterstitial = buildInterstitialAd()..load();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myInterstitial.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Test Ad App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ButtonBar(
          alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('BannerAd'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BannerAdPage()));
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('InterstitialAd'),
              onPressed: () {
                showInterstitialAd();
                //showRandomInterstitialAd();
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InterstitialAdPage()),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InterstitialAdPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('InterstitialAd Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BannerAdPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BannerAdPageState createState() => _BannerAdPageState();
}

class _BannerAdPageState extends State<BannerAdPage> {

  BannerAd myBanner;

  BannerAd buildBannerAd() {
    return BannerAd(
        adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
        size: AdSize.banner,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
          if (event == MobileAdEvent.loaded) {
            myBanner..show();
          }
        });
  }

  BannerAd buildLargeBannerAd() {
    return BannerAd(
        adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
        size: AdSize.largeBanner,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
          if (event == MobileAdEvent.loaded) {
            myBanner
              ..show(
                  anchorType: AnchorType.top,
                  anchorOffset: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15);
          }
        });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
    myBanner = buildBannerAd()..load();
    //myBanner = buildLargeBannerAd()..load();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myBanner.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('BannerAd Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am looking for how to remove the "Test Ad" text that show on top of every Ad when the ad displays

Comment: Please post your code and specify which Admob plugin you're using. Thanks

Comment: I just edit it and added my code

Answer (score 3):

There are three possible reasons why "Test Ad" shows up:

1. You are testing the AdMob on emulator.
2. If you're testing on a real device and the text is still there you are using google's free testing ids.
3. If you using your own google ad id then publish your app. After
   publishing this text is removed.

Comment: hi @sumit 
I uploading the app in test flight and still see the test mode label.
any Idea about it?

Comment: @AliAzimoshan as mentioned in the third point, I guess after app is live on app store/play store that text will go.

Comment: Did this end up working?